# Magento 1.4: Disabling all products in a particular category

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I need to disable all products that are in a particular category (the category itself is disabled but the products must not show in search, either).

I found [this blog post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/administration-magento/bulk-disable-multiple-magento-products/) but that's for an older version of Magento than 1.4 - the database structure has changed and I don't know how to adjust the SQL accordingly.

The filtering of products could alternatively be done on a dropdown attribute if that's easier, as all products with this attribute set a certain way are in the category.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the [enhanced admin product grid](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/WDCA/extension/748/enhanced-product-grid) you can configure it to show the categories: from there you could filter by the category you want and then use "actions" dropdown to disable the products.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Just Export the products in your store, then filter the spreadsheet by the category you want to affect. Now you only have the products in that category. Change the Status to disabled and then import the products with the updated status to make the change.